# Drupal 7 - How to show an upcoming event from site 1 on site 2?

Tags: datetime

For Drupal 7, Is it possible to show an upcoming event from site A on site B's block?

Also, is it possible to show an upcoming event by category? For example, I wanna have an upcoming event for swimming class and an upcoming event for hiking group. However, they are all in one same calendar.

Thanks,
HL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Shared Blocks](https://drupal.org/project/sharedblocks), it has both drupal 6 and 7 stable releases:

```
If you have a main site with blocks that you want to syndicate across several
other websites, you need this module!

Features:

Allows publishing and subscribing of Drupal blocks
Changes to published blocks are updated on sites with subscription blocks
Published blocks provides a JSON endpoint at sharedblocks/{module}/{delta}
Block subscriptions are updated on cron with an adjustable refresh interval
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Remote blocks](https://drupal.org/project/remoteblocks) module. to display 'site A' data on 'site B'. For more info go through the module documentation.

On 'site A' create a view having filter event date is greater than current date.You can also apply category filtration as per your requirement.

Comment: Ty Rupesh, but the Remote Block only available for drupal 6 :(

Comment: @H-L Why are you not mentioned Drupal version in question ?

Comment: Sorry Rupesh, I will edit my question now.